# Parent Div Needs to extend with Multiple Children

Tags: html, css, display, html4

My parent Div needs to extend with all the children.
The children divs are multiple buttons that's x position is incremental.

Example

```
div id="Parent"
  div id="Child" /div {X-position : 90}
  div id="Child2" /div {X-position : 180}
/div
```

Any Ideas will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting the `display: inline-block;` or `display: table;` to the parent div, and then it will fit the size of its children:

```
.Parent{
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    /* display: table;*/
}

.Child{
    background-color:blue;
    width:50px;
    heigth:50px;
}
```

You can see [the **demo** here](http://jsfiddle.net/7urx213p/1/):

```css
.parent{
    background-color:red;
    display:table;
}

.child{
    background-color:blue;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">bbb</div>
    <div class="child">aaa</div>
    <div class="child">bbb</div>
    <div class="child">aaa</div>
    <div class="child">bbb</div>
    <div class="child">aaa</div> 
</div>
```